# Traverse This Node in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to traverse this node I got back from an AJAX call, and am having problems doing so. I am trying to access the `name` node which is located in `facet/#/@attributes/name`. I am  currently at the `#` level but am confused on how to access the `@ attributes` level.

```
console.log(data.categories); //outputs what you see below.
$(data.categories.facet).each( function(key, value) {
    console.log(key + ' : ' + value.attributes); //outputs undefined
});
```

[image]

Comment: `console.log(key + ' : ' + value['@attributes'].name);`

Comment: @Musa I keep getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) `

Comment: Sorry typo `console.log(key + ' : ' + value['@attributes'].name);`

Comment: @Musa Great, thanks. Can you post your response as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use square bracket notation `[]` to access properties of an object which contain special characters like the `@` in `@attributes`.

```
console.log(key + ' : ' + value['@attributes'].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to what I assume is chrome's console.

But does facet[0].name not return "rating"?